# DrawText with outline using GDI (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm using this code to sign a frame from webcam:

```
Font = CreateFont(18, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, "times");

...

HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
unsigned char * img = 0;
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &BMI, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&img, NULL, 0);
memcpy(img, CameraFrame.data, CameraFrame.size());
free(CameraFrame.data);
CameraFrame.data = img;
SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
SelectObject(hDC, Font);
SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255,255,255));
string Text = "Test";
DrawTextA(hDC, Text.c_str(), Text.size(), &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);
DeleteDC(hDC);
```

Of course the color scale of frames will differ, and I need the text to be visible anyway.

**How to `DrawText` with outline?** For example, white text with black outline.

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not (easily) possible using plain GDI. GDI+, on the other hand, allows you to do that. There's a CodeProject article ([Outline Text](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42529/Outline-Text)) with lots of samples.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty easy.  Use GDI paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

- Draw the Text in black, but scaled slightly larger by 2 pixels (good luck) and *offset* by (-1,-1) then normally in white in the center.
- Draw the Text in black, but offset `{ (-1,-1), (1,1), (-1,1), (1,-1) }` and then in white in the center.

Comment: First suggestion won't work, because the background (outline) won't scale horizontally with the text. Second suggestion doesn't create an outline, rather something resembling a shadow effect.

Comment: I've used the second technique suggested for this purpose in the pass, but I found it necessary to also use a total of eight offsets, the four diagonal ones suggested plus the four orthogonal ones.  This makes the outline contiguous even if the characters have diagonals.  You can argue whether it's an outline or a shadow, but it does a fine job separating the text from the background.

Comment: Yeah, I used the technique for years before upgrading my font system to Signed Distance Fields.

Comment: The second solution gives a result like CSS `text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;` - exactly what I need! Great THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

With GDI, you can use BeginPath, DrawText, EndPath, and then StrokeAndFillPath, as long as you're using an "outline" font (like TrueType or OpenType).

```
  ::BeginPath(ps.hdc);
  RECT rc;
  GetClientRect(&rc);
  ::DrawTextW(ps.hdc, L"Hello", 5, &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
  ::EndPath(ps.hdc);
  ::StrokeAndFillPath(ps.hdc);
```

The StrokeAndFillPath will use the currently selected pen for the outline and the currently selected brush to fill it in.  You can use TextOut or other GDI calls inside the BeginPath/EndPath.

You won't get any anti-aliasing like you'd have with regular text output, so it won't be as crisp as your regular ClearType text.  At larger sizes, this isn't a big issue.

Comment: Does this actually work? Because `DrawText()` is not listed as one of the supported APIs that can be used with `BeginPath()`. If it does, it's either a doc bug or an undocumented implementation detail which I wouldn't rely on.

Comment: I extracted it from working code.  I learned the technique many years ago, so I'm surprised to hear it's not documented.  DrawText boils down to the moral equivalent of TextOut or ExtTextOut, so I'd be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: I think the reason DrawText isn't listed in the GDI path documentation is that it's technically a User function rather than a GDI function.  But it uses GDI under the hood, so it works just fine.

Comment: Thank you! In general it works. But the quality is disgusting. Any ideas how to make text more readable?

Comment: @Iceman:  No simple ideas that use vanilla GDI.  For small text, I've used the second bullet in James Poag's answer, which gives decent separation between the background and the text.  Could you just blank out the area behind the text with a rectangle of solid color?  Anything fancier requires a lot of work or using a higher-level rendering system that will antialias when stroking the path.

Comment: @Iceman:  I was revisiting this today and came up with a compromise.  The problem is that StrokeAndFillPath doesn't do antialiasing.  So instead of StrokeAndFillPath, I use StrokePath and then draw the text again with a regular TextOutW (or DrawTextW).  The outer edge of the shadow/border is still blocky, but the characters themselves are antialiased.  It's not perfect, but it looks a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would recommend:

1. Create a custom pen with a dashed style using CreatePen or ExtCreatePen with PS_DASH.
2. DrawText using DT_CALCRECT and your desired styles to see where the text will actually go.
3. SelectObject the HPEN from #1 into your HDC
4. Use MoveToEx and LineTo to draw the 4 edges of your frame based on the rectangle retrieved in #2 (adding some padding as needed). Sample code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145182(v=vs.85).aspx

Step 1 happens when initializing. Steps 2-4 happen each time you paint.